# Is it true that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{f(x_{n})}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{f(y_{n})}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

If for all sequence $x_n\rightarrow 0$, the sequence ${f(x_n)}$ is converges,

can i say that it's true that for $x_n,y_n\rightarrow 0$, i will get:

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{f(x_{n})}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{f(y_{n})}$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: You might consider the sequence $\{x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, x_3, y_3, \ldots\}$.

Comment: that's what i try and got it's true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. If you would have two sequences $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$  and $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that converge to zero and for which $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = L_1$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(y_n) = L_2$ and $L_1 \neq L_2$ then for the sequence

$$ z_n := \begin{cases} x_n & n \textrm{ is even} \\ y_n & n \textrm{ is odd} \end{cases} $$

you would have that $z_n \to 0$ but $f(z_n)$ would have two subsequences $f(z_{2n})$ and $f(z_{2n+1})$ that converge to two different limits and so $f(z_n)$ won't have a limit.

Comment: i didn't understand. {$f(x_n)$} will still converges.

Comment: if $\{a_n\} \to L$, then all subsequences converge to the same limit. If two subsequences converge to a limit, you have a contradiction to the fact that  $\{a_n\}$ converges.

Comment: @ Andres Mejia - but what you say it's about sequence here it's function.

Comment: $f(z_{2n}) = f(x_{2n})$ will converge to $L_1$ (being a subsequence of a sequence that converges to $L_1$) while $f(z_{2n+1}) = f(y_{2n+1})$ will converge to $L_2$ to $f(z_n)$ won't converge.